# File path into variable in XSL

Tags: variables, xslt, filepath

I have a file that is not in the same place that the xsl file. How to add the file path into a variable in my xsl file ?

There is the following error when i execute the xsl file :
No files found for transformation by stylesheet

Code :

```
   <xsl:variable name="filename" select="'../../file.xml'" />
   <xsl:for-each select="document($filename)>
      ...
   </xsl:for-each>
```

Thank

Comment: try <xsl:variable name="filename"><xsl:text>../../file.xml</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? You've just declared a variable and assigned a string value to it. What did you expect?

Comment: How do you use the filename variable later - can you provide us with an example or a short snippet?

Comment: Your variable represents a string with a value of "../../file.xml". I suspect that your issues lies where you are calling ($filename) and parsing the string into a actual path. Can you post the relaviant code?

Comment: I don't think you can run an XSL transformation without giving the processor *some* source XML - even if it's a dummy one, e.g. a file containing only `<root/>`. *Then* you can reference another file in the stylesheet and tell your stylesheet to get data from it. Of course, if you know in advance the path to the XML file and its name, you could just pass it to the processor when initiating the transformation. There is no rule that the two documents - XML and XSLT - must be in the same directory.

Answer (score 4):

You may get it, if you are using XSLT 2.0:

Suppose, I have any directory '/C:/Users/vgv/Desktop/Testing' which has sub directories, multiples files, and my XSLT 'WBC.xsl' and I want to search 'catalog.xml' file only. I may use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="XSLPath" select="base-uri(doc(.))"/>
  <xsl:param name="Files" select="collection(concat(substring-before($XSLPath,concat('/',tokenize($XSLPath,'/')[last()])),'?select=catalog.xml;recurse=yes'))"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$XSLPath"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="base-uri($Files)"/></xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces message:

```
file:/C:/Users/vgv/Desktop/Testing/WBC.xsl
file:/C:/Users/vgv/Desktop/Testing/fxsl-xslt2/catalog.xml
```

Comment: If i have wbc.xsl in some other default location except c:/users how to define?

Comment: You may change collection in this case 'collection('file:///d:/someDir/?select=*.*')' . Please have a look on this URL for more information http://www.xmlplease.com/collection.